# Powershell Script to audit all mapped drives in an OU

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

Similar to this post: http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/9777/16289.aspx
I'm looking for a powershell script that will let me query all the machines in an OU on my network and see what drives they have mapped, either by user or GP. I've tried running the second script down in the post and I'm getting the same error the previous question poster got:

> Test-Connection : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argume
>   nt that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
>   At line:22 char:33
>   if(Test-Connection -ComputerName <<<< $child.name -Count 1 -Quiet){
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Connection], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

If anyone can help get this script running or suggest a different solution I'd greatly appreciate it.
-Adam

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to include the code you're using, instead of linking to another site for it.  But your error boils down to: Somewhere in your `foreach($child in $children)` loop, the `$child.name` (and possibly `$child`) is empty or `$null`, therefore `Test-Connection` cannot go and ping the computer name.